# How to obtain and plot the RSI data of 100 stocks at the same time

Tags: tradingview-api, rsi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPbfN.png)
I created an indicator called RSI Bitmap. I intended to provide users with a more intuitive perspective. The request.security function I used can only obtain the RSI data of 40 stocks at most.

How can I get the RSI data of 100 or more stocks?

How can I get the RSI data of 100 or more stocks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this screener](https://www.tradingview.com/script/0h0gKNcy-120x-ticker-screener-composite-tickers/) for 120 symbols

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I am also willing to share my results, please be patient, thank you

Comment: 1_ Don't put your code on Github. 2_ If you have a new question, make a new post.